# Export .xlsx file based on conditions in PowerShell data mining

Tags: excel, powershell, automation, conditional-statements, export-to-excel

I have the code below which imports an Excel file and then exports the workbook into one sheet:

```
$sheets = (Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path 'C:\TEMP\Template\TemplateName.xlsx').Name 
$i = 1
foreach ($sheet in $sheets) {
    Import-Excel -WorksheetName $sheet -Path 'C:\TEMP\Template\TemplateName.xlsx' -StartRow 5 -HeaderName 'Property','Current settings','Proposed settings' | Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\Template\Changes.xlsx -AutoSize
    Write-Progress -Activity "Generating Changes" -Status "Worksheet $i of $($sheets.Count) completed" -PercentComplete (($i / $sheets.Count) * 100)  
    $i++
}
```

The problem with the code above is that it outputs the xlsx file last row first and then goes in reverse. I would like to maintain the original order of the imported file.

Secondly, I've been playing with different ways to assign columns to PS Object and use Where-Object to filter the output, but can't figure it out.

What I'd like to do is if the Column "Current settings" is blank or does NOT match text in column "Proposed settings", then leave that row out of the export. Essentially, I would just like to fill in rows where "Current settings" is not blank and -notmatch "Proposed settings.

Comment: Ask the new question with the details (add as much information as possible) and if I see it and know how to do what you are looking for I'll answer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see on your code, aside from not filtering the **Current settings** column, is that you're outputting to your Excel file on each iteration of your outer loop, hence, you're replacing the output for the contents of the last Worksheet (this is because you're not using `-Append` switch).

However, the proper and efficient way to do it, instead of appending to a file first generate the output you want in memory and then output it to the file once (**this applies always as long as the file fits in memory**).

```
$param = @{
    Path       = 'C:\TEMP\Template\TemplateName.xlsx'
    StartRow   = 5
    HeaderName = 'Property', 'Current settings', 'Proposed settings'
}

# foreach worksheet in this file
Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path 'C:\TEMP\Template\TemplateName.xlsx' | ForEach-Object {
    # set the worksheetname name in $param
    $param['WorksheetName'] = $_.Name
    # import the worksheet and enumerate it
    foreach($line in Import-Excel @param) {
        $currSettings = $line.'Current settings'
        $propSettings = $line.'Proposed settings'
        # if the value of 'Current settings' cell is equal to the value of
        # 'Proposed settings' cell OR is empty / white spaces, skip it, go to next iteration
        if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings)) {
            continue
        }
        # if we're here, condition before this was not true, hence we want to
        # output this line
        $line
    }
} | Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\Template\Changes.xlsx -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. That makes sense! The code works great, except that it still pulls in rows where "Current settings" match "Proposed settings". Any way to leave out the rows where the values of those two columns have the same text value?

Comment: @RADical omg, i'm dumb, I thought you wanted to skip the rows where the value of the `Current settings` column had a literal "Proposed settings" instead of comparing one cell against the other (this is what you are looking for correct?)

Comment: You're way smarter than I am. LOL. I think I figured it out. There might be a better way to do it, but I modified the code you posted slightly to get there. Thanks so much again for your help!

`if($cell -eq $null -or $cell -match $line.'Proposed settings')

Comment: @RADical see my update, I think that should be it :)

Comment: You're the man!!! Thanks! One other quick question. Do you know if there is a way to add the title from A2 of each sheet when it moves between sheets? For e.g. I would like to insert the title of each sheet when differences are found on that particular sheet.

Comment: @RADical happy to help, I'm not sure I understand, you could ask a new question with the details so it's easier to follow. If this answer helped you solve the initial question please consider accepting it